# is low pitched machine synthesized speech easier to comprehend at high rates?

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, language-processing, speech, sensory-perception, speech-comprehension

all I have is anecdotal experience,
[try it out yourself](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/).

I couldn't find any published study,
was anything published about that?